# How to right-click in Unity Webapps new browser

Tags: unity, webapps

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying some webapps (Facebook, Twitter, etc). Firefox was the used browser in earlier versions, but now a dedicated browser is used instead. The problem is that I don't know how to copy, paste, or any action other than click.

Right click doesn't seem to work, nor CTRL+C/V , so I can't do any basic action such as copying a password.

Is there any way to do it that I don't know about?

Comment: Is the Ubuntu Browser set as default for Websites? Check in *System Settings* -> *Default Applications*

Comment: Nope, Firefox is the default for "regular" websites. Ubuntu Browser is the default just for WebApps. Firefox works ok, the problem is just for Webapps. I know, I could just forget about them and just use FF, but I think it would be nice to use them since they are available...

Comment: I have the same situation here. Not able to right-click or even opening links when using Ubuntu Browser (opens automatically with any webapp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently that is a [bug in webapps](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webbrowser-app/+bug/1264493).

It looks as if someone worked on it already. So hopefully this issue will be resolved in the future. For the moment I don't know a way to get it to work.