# How to change ubuntu (admin) user's password on a live USB (with casper-rw)?

Tags: usb, password

I'm trying to set a password for the ubuntu user on my live usb. I managed to google some of the way - and ubuntu now boots to a log in screen every time i boot. So far so good.

When i try to change the password with:
passwd ubuntu

It says password updated successfully.

However when i reboot it's defaults back to no password.

How do i make it "stick"?

Comment: Is this a persistence live usb stick?

Comment: You can add a new user with password to a persistent drive, my experience is that it will be difficult to shut down the computer. see http://askubuntu.com/questions/582675/shutdown-persistent-usb-install