# Preventing freezing in Ubuntu 20.04 running from live USB

Tags: live-usb, freeze

When I am running Ubuntu 20.04 from a live USB (without installing it) it usually happens that when a certain degree of activity  is reached (i.e lots of programs running and/or lot of internet tabs with videos at the same time) or a lot of memory is used (many downloads, for example) the laptop freezes totally and I am forced to turn off it by pressing the power button (no solutions like [the ones exposed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743570/random-freezing-with-ubuntu-14-04) work).

As I have resigned myself to it I would like at least to know if I can monitor that process in any way: i.e. if **I can check any indicator or program which tell me that the activity has reached certain level that makes this freezing likely** (I don't know which one is exactly the parameter I should check, I guess the RAM memory, but not sure)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's any help, but this sounds like a USB stick limitation. I ran Ubuntu from a USB stick for a year for work and found that things got very unreliable when I used anything which needed a lot of disk access, like Docker. If I was doing this again I'd use an external SSD instead. I know it's a pain but is there any way you can try a different USB drive?

Comment: You can check RAM use in terminal by typing `free`. Ubuntu tries to run in RAM if not enough RAM things slow down, You did not mention how you made the USB. If it is booting ISO files stored on a NTFS partition it will not power off.

Comment: This is pretty old but may still work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/582675/shutdown-persistent-usb-install